# Batch normalization getting Val accuracy of 000e00

Tags: cnn, accuracy, batch-normalization, epochs

I am currently stuck on batch normalization. I have code written out but when I do it it keeps giving me a val_accuracy of 00e00 and stops after 2 epochs (I am wanting to run 20). I am not sure what to change or add to fix it.

My code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D, LeakyReLU, Flatten, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop

# First Layer 

model2 = Sequential()


model2.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), padding = 'same', activation = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)))  #layer 1 

model2.add(MaxPooling2D())

model2.add(BatchNormalization())

# Adding the bach normalization then flattening 

model2.add(Dropout(0.2))

model2.add(BatchNormalization())

model2.add(Flatten())


model2.add(Dense(2, activation = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)))

adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

model2.summary()

Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 32)        896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling  (None, 32, 32, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_11 (Bat  (None, 32, 32, 32)       128       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_12 (Bat  (None, 32, 32, 32)       128       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 flatten_4 (Flatten)         (None, 32768)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 65538     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 66,690
Trainable params: 66,562
Non-trainable params: 128
________________________________________

model2.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 2),
             ModelCheckpoint('.mdl_wts.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True)]
history2 = model2.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size = 32, callbacks = callbacks, validation_split = 0.2, epochs = 20, verbose = 1)
```